# Modifying the amount of posts visible per page in Anchor CMS

Tags: php, anchor-cms

I'm building a site in [Anchor CMS](http://anchorcms.com/) and am loving it, all except for the forums being down and their documentation being so light.

I'd like to change the amount of posts that appear on my post page. [The documentation](http://anchorcms.com/docs/function-reference/posts) states that I just need to change that figure in the config... but where is the config, or where in the [config](http://anchorcms.com/docs/function-reference/config)?

```
<?php if(has_posts()): ?> // adding numbers to has_post('n') does nothing   
  <?php $i = 0; while(posts()): $i++; ?> // adding numbers to posts('n') does nothing either
     // POST STUFF
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you are running an outdated version of your site, update anchor by going to `yoursite.com/admin/update` as older versions of Anchor do not support pagination.

The "config" I was searching for is located in **Extend -> Site Metadata**

[image]

From there you will find a range selector that adjusts the amount of posts visible per page:

[image]

Moving the selector all the way to the right will display the maximum amount of posts possible (the amount of which I am unsure of). All the way to the left, and you will only see 1 post per page, all the way to the right... well, I'm unsure of the limit, but I can affirm it's more than 9.